# How can I test my data connector without getting a permission error?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm building a Google Data Studio data connector. When I want to test it by clicking the link for the `Latest (head)` deployment, I get a white page saying I "need permission to perform this action". How can I fix this, so I can test my script in Google Data Studio?

[image: You need permission to perform this action]

Answer (score 0):

1. First confirm that you can open and edit reports in Data Studio.
2. If you have multiple Google accounts logged in at the same time, make sure the same user is using Apps Script and Data Studio.
3. Once you click on the deployment link, it should trigger the Google oAuth flow. You will need to complete the oAuth flow to view the connector.

Comment: Minhaz, I first logged out of all Google accounts, then logged in to one. I can now open and edit reports in Data Studio. Once I click the deployment link, I get a white page with a Google logo and a message (see screenshot description). In a video I found on the subject, I saw someone manually change the user part of the connector link, is that something you've heard of before?

Comment: Interesting. Are you on a regular gmail account or a G Suite account?

Comment: G suite. But that’s a good point. Will try on a regular account.